# Is there a way to prevent 'dragend' event in parent Konva.Group when a child is dragged and both child and parent are draggable?

Tags: konvajs

I have a Konva.Group which is draggable. Within this group I add another Konva.Group which has yet another draggable Konva.Group. So the relationship is like this:

parent group -> child group -> child group

Now when I try to drag my last draggable child I also get 'dragend' event in the parent, although the parent stays at the same position.

So I only get this parent 'dragend' event. The dragging of the child works correctly, it's just the parent event that seems not right.

The workaround that I found so far looks like this:

```
let _this = this;
this.on('dragmove', (evt) => {
  if(evt.target._id == _this._id){
  //my handler code
  }
}
```

But is it a bug actually or expected behavior and I just need to somehow prevent event propagation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. That is expected behavior of event bubbling (event propagation). It works for all drag events.

There are two ways to resolve the issue.

#### (1) Cancel Event Bubble

https://konvajs.org/docs/events/Cancel_Propagation.html

```js
childGroup.on('dragend', (e) => {
  evt.cancelBubble = true;
});
```

#### (2) Filter in event

That is what you did in your workaround. `e.target` points to a node that was dragged. So you can use it to check the logic of event callback.

```js
parentGroup.on('dragend', (e) => {
  // do nothing if any child was dragged
  if (e.target !== parentGroup) {
    return;
  }
  // do some logic here
});
```